# BrowserStack Options App: Key value pair Errors During Execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, webdriver-io, browserstack

Using node v14.17.1 (npm v6.14.13), Cucumber/BDD.
The Package.json file has the following dependencies.

//////////

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^17.0.11",
    "@wdio/appium-service": "^7.7.3",
    "@wdio/browserstack-service": "^7.7.4",
    "@wdio/cli": "^7.7.4",
    "@wdio/cucumber-framework": "^7.7.3",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^7.7.4",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.7.4",
    "@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.7.4",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.7.3",
    "@wdio/sync": "^7.7.4",
    "browserstack-local": "^1.4.8",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "chromedriver": "^91.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "geckodriver": "^2.0.0",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^3.1.1",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.1.0",
    "wdio-cucumberjs-json-reporter": "^3.0.0",
    "wdio-json-steps-reporter": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@wdio/runner": "^7.7.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "p-iteration": "^1.1.8",
    "webdriverio": "^7.7.4"
  },
```

////////
Custom capabilities for BrowserStack:

```
case "android":
      return {
        platformName: "android",
        "bstack:options": {
          os: "android",
          osVersion: "10.0",
          **app: "my/test"**,
          deviceName: "Google Pixel 3",
          appiumVersion: "1.19.1",
          local: "true",
          acceptInsecureCerts: "true",
          debug: "true",
          networkLogs: "true",
        },
```

//////
When a test is executed, the following error is displayed.

```
[0-6] 2021-06-23T00:35:23.947Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 200 due to Error: The property '#/alwaysMatch/bstack:options' contains additional properties ["app"] outside of the schema when none are allowed in the payload.
```

What is the **correct key(name)** for 'application'? I tried this https://www.browserstack.com/automate/capabilities. Did not help. In the same framework, the custom capabilities for Web are applied correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the one you are looking for is `project` or `name`.

From the page you referred, their purpose is as below.

`project: Allows the user to specify a name for a logical group of builds.`

`name: Allows the user to specify an identifier for the test run.`